# Integrate Casl with Featherjs-Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, casl

I am trying to setup roles and permissions to handle api requests. I am using Feathers.js with feathers-sequelize for a PostGres db.

For managing roles and permissions I am using casl.js:
https://github.com/stalniy/casl

Most of the examples for integrating Casl are mongo/mongoose based.
I read the following article after:
https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/database/integration/2017/07/22/database-integration.html

In the example provided they use sequelize scopes, at the moment feathers-sequelize doesnt support sequelize-scopes with paramters (from what I can see)

Long story short, I am trying to find a way of integrating feathers-sequelize with Casl to manage resource permissions.

So far I can construct the Casl 'abilities' per user, but now to connect those abilities to the database is where I am stuck.

When using Mongo/mongoose its easy as you simply do toMongoQuery and pass in the parameters.

If there is anything that I need to add please do let me know, not sure how to get help on this particular issue.

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So managed to resolve the issue:
I copied this code:
https://github.com/stalniy/casl-feathersjs-example/blob/master/src/hooks/abilities.js

Then I adapted it by adding the following function:

```
function ruleToQuery(rule) {
  if (JSON.stringify(rule.conditions).includes('"$all":')) {
    throw new Error('Sequelize does not support "$all" operator')
  }
  return rule.inverted ? { $not: rule.conditions } : rule.conditions
}
```

Then I replaced this line:

```
const query = toMongoQuery(ability, serviceName, action)
```

with

```
const query = rulesToQuery(ability, action, serviceName, ruleToQuery)
```

After importing

```
const { rulesToQuery } = require('@casl/ability/extra');
```

One of my issues was the way I was creating my permissions which is not directly related to Feathers nor CASL.

If you have a similar issue but the answer above isnt clear please comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`params.sequelize`](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#paramssequelize) or `params.query` + [`toSequelizeQuery` function](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/database/integration/2017/07/22/database-integration.html#other-databases).

Look at [CASL Feathers example](https://github.com/stalniy/casl-feathersjs-example) to see an example how I did this for [`feathers-mongoose`](https://github.com/stalniy/casl-feathersjs-example/blob/master/src/hooks/abilities.js#L63)

Comment: @Sergil Thanks for the reply.
I did look at the CASL Feathers example, the line that I am trying to figure out for Sequelize is:
`const query = toMongoQuery(ability, serviceName, action)`

I see you mention: params.sequelize & params.query + toSequelizeQuery. Could you please elaborate how I can use these? I did try follow the example on:
 https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/database/integration/2017/07/22/database-integration.html, but hit a few hurdles.

Thanks again.

Comment: does this make sense so far, replace the line:
`const query = toMongoQuery(ability, serviceName, action)` with
`const query = toSequelizeQuery(ability, 'roles');`

Then where would I include the params.query part?

Comment: Yes. You can try. I believe that should at least partially work. If you have a project/example on github I can check it